# Sorting algorithm most suitable for sorting array that is almost sorted

Tags: algorithm, sorting

What sorting algorithm would be most suitable to use when sorting an array that is already almost sorted?

Comment: Define "almost sorted"?  What may look "almost sorted" to a human may be very different to a machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insertion sort will work well for almost-sorted data. You get close to optimal results.

Here's a great animation which shows how the sort will perform: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/insertion-sort

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Thank you is this as it takes 1 pass through the data @StilesCrisis

Comment: There is a nice explanation with an animated picture here: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/insertion-sort

Comment: Wow, @gd1, love this website you found!

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  Size of array?  what does "already almost sorted" mean - as in what percentage of the data is already in sequential order?  what is your programming and data storage environment - is the data in memory, a database, a file?

Having said that, you might start by researching Timsort.  It is a relatively new sort algorithm that will handle large datasets, taking advantage of "runs" (data already in sort order).

Comment: Yes already almost sorted as in the percentage of data that is already in sequential order

Answer (score 0):

If you define "almost sorted" as having a low number of pairs of data points that are in reverse order instead of the correct order (e.g., imagine taking a sorted list and then taking disjoint consecutive pairs of data points and reversing them), then a bubble sort will work very well where you make one modification that if you swap two elements, then you keep searching to the left and swapping as long as the neighboring elements are out of order. This will have complexity O(n) if the number of pairs out of order is O(n).

Comment: That's true, but insertion sort is still better than bubble in this case. It does a similar sort with less wasted steps.